# Replugging of one wired ethernet connection for three systems only working after a long wait

Tags: linux, networking, router, windows-8.1, ethernet

I'm living in a dorm house of more than 200 students and each room has one ethernet wall plug.

On my laptop I'm running Ubuntu and I also have a dual boot PC running Win 8 and Manjaro Linux.

I only ever use one of those three systems and on Windows and Ubuntu the Internet works fine.

But as soon as I replug the cable on the respective other systme (PC -> Laptop / Laptop -> PC) or if I reboot from Winows into Manjaro, the Internet doesn't work for some time. I couldn't figure out yet, what makes it work again, usually it takes between 1 to 10 minutes in which I try restarting, reconnecting or just leaving it alone. All those three methods have worked before.

On my third system (manjaro), I haven't been able to have Internet access yet at all.

In all three systems, whenever I plug in the cable, a network is recognized and an IP adress is generated. Even the correct speed is displayed (this is displayed on Linux systems).

I wish to find a way/hack to gain Internet right away. In some occasions I'm working on something and don't have the time to wait 10 minutes to gain back Internet.

I'm suspecting some Router funkyness, but I don't have access to it.

1. I wish to understand what's happening so I can take steps whenever I switch systems so that i gain back Internet in a reliable way
2. Eventually, I wish to find a way to not have to worry about the replugging, and the three systems are set up in a way to work without intervention after each replug.

Comment: You might not believe it, but I can't get Internet connectivity if my OS date/time is off by more than a few minutes. When you dual-boot between Win and Linux, check and adjust the OS's date-time first before hooking up the ethernet cable. Let me know how you go. I couldn't believe this was an issue until I experienced (and replicated) it myself.